# Installing tomcat 9 on oracle linux having tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7, springboot, tomcat9

I have a task to deploy a war file of a Springboot 2.2.4 therefore the oracle linux server i am using already contains tomcat 7, and springboot 2.2.4 is not compatible with tomcat7 I am getting an error of manager no classdef found,

how can I install  tomcat 9 and operates two tomcats(tomcat 7 and 9)  in the same server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and upack last tomcat using these commands:

```
curl -O http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.33/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.33.tar.gz

tar -zxvf apache-tomcat-9.0.33.tar.gz
```

If you want to have them both running simultaneously you have to change port attribute in `Connector` and `Server` tag in file `conf/server.xml` to different one than currently existing on old tomcat.